# Count on trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, count, aggregate

Can we perform count operation inside a trigger?

I have a table TB1 with fields id,title,author,date. I want to create a trigger that when ever I will insert a row in tb1. A trigger should run and the total no of authors in the tb1 should show in a new table total.
I have written the code

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER insertintonew2
AFTER
INSERT ON tb1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE total
SET total_author = (select count(*) from tb1);
END;
$$
```

The output I am getting a is populated with total_author column name but the count value is not populated.
Can anyone tell me why is it happening?

Comment: Your code looks okay to me.

Comment: Try the inner query outside the trigger.

Comment: I don't see any obvious syntax errors and your trigger should be working.  Can you try running `select count(*) from tb1`  and post the results?

Comment: Are there any rows in the `total` table?  I tried what you have, and nothing happened until I first added a row to the `total` table. There is nothing to `update` if no rows exist.